# how to implement method that return object based on type passed

Tags: c#, generics

I need to implement a method which returns an object based on type like.

```
 public interface IBase
{ 
}
public class Base1 : IBase { }
public class Base2 : IBase { }
public class Base3 : IBase { }
public class MyClass
{
    public IBase GetObject<T>() where T:IBase
    {
        // should return the object based on type.
        return null;
    }

}
```

Do i need to maintain dictionary like inside the GetObject method?

```
            Dictionary<Type, IBase> test = new Dictionary<Type, IBase>();
```

Is there any better way for same?

[Edit]: - I dont want to create the object everytime. I need to keep it inside memory and when there is a call. I want to return the object from there. Apart from dictionary is there any other way?

Comment: Can you post the desired usage with specific types?

Comment: Your question re: maintaining a dictionary depends entirely on whether you want to create new objects, or return cached objects. You need some more info in your question to clarify usage.

Comment: Ok, why do you want to keep objects created? One reason could be creation object is expensive, and you want to cache them and there may be more than one instance of object instances. The other case is you want to ensure, there will be only one instance of an object (i.e Singleton Pattern), in that case you can still use my answer, where you use a new operator, but only one instance of object will ever be created. Then no need to create the dictionary, which is not that elegant in my opinion. I'll edit the answer to show this

Comment: yes Raiden creation of object is expensive and I cant create them everytime requested.

Comment: Do you want more than one instance of one type? or Is it okay to limit it to one instance?

Comment: I think what you are trying to implement here is a Factory pattern. In that case I think it's okay to use the Dictionary, its not bad choice there. have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

Comment: thanks Raiden, I will go thru it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyClass {
    public IBase GetObject<T>() where T:IBase, new() // EDIT: Added new constraint 
    {
        // should return the object based on type.
        return new T();
    }

}
```

Comment: Needs a new() constraint in there as well, as IBase is an interface.

Comment: Edited the answer with new constraint.

Comment: @DJ You could use [Singletons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx), but it seems to have more similar code to write...I would probably choose Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

In your case you have two ways:

1) create your own collection and maintain it by yourself (something like this)

```
public interface IBase {}
public class Base1 : IBase { public int x; }
public class Base2 : IBase { public int y; }
public class Base3 : IBase { public int z; }

public class MyClass
{
    Dictionary<Type, IBase> m_typesCollection;

    public MyClass()
    {
        // for example
        m_typesCollection = new Dictionary<Type, IBase>();
        m_typesCollection.Add(typeof(Base1), new Base1());
        m_typesCollection.Add(typeof(Base2), new Base2());
    }

    public IBase GetObject<T>()
        where T : IBase, new()
    {
        if (m_typesCollection.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            return m_typesCollection[typeof(T)];
        m_typesCollection.Add(typeof(T), new T());
        return m_typesCollection[typeof(T)];
    }
}
```

2) - use Dependency injection container as collection to your types

Answer (score 2):

You could add the `new()` constraint to your generic type parameter. Please, read [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). It then would look somewhat like this:

```
public T GetObject<T>() where T : IBase, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

and use it

```
IBase b = GetObject<Base1>();
```

---

Actually, there is a built-in method to create objects, based on type, i.e. [Activator.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx)

```
IBase b = Activator.CreateInstance<Base1>();
```